# Should I return value or use void?

Tags: java

For example, I have a method called "filterTop3Items(List list)". Should I return result or return void?

```
public List<Item> filterTop3Items(List<Item> list>;
```

or

```
public void filterTop3Items(List<Item> list);
```

The second one will modify the input parameter.

What is the best practice for this, in terms of maintainability?

EDIT:
For case 1:

```
List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
... (add item multiple times) ...

List<Item> filteredList = filterTop3Items(list);
... (process filteredList) ...
```

For case 2;

```
List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
... (add item multiple times) ...

filterTop3Items(list);
... (process list) ...
```

For case 2, If you are trying to understand the code, you have to keep track of the operations in order to understand what is inside the list. For case 1, reader can understand the code by just looking at the variable name "filteredList". This is one of the maintainability issues.

Comment: It depends whether your callsites want to mutate their parameter.

Comment: If you `return` you imply that you return a copy. If you `return void` then you are saying that the method mutates the input. So the question is _what does your method do_?

Comment: The answer depends on your requirements, not maintainability. One important thing to consider, however, is what *else* might have a reference to the original list.

Comment: From the name I would prefer the second approach.  If I wanted the top 3 items from an unmodified list, I'd call it something like top3Items().  That is, you're saying, "filter this list:" which implies that the list will be affected.

Comment: One important thing to consider is that if you return the filtered list (be it a copy or the original modified), it allows chaining multiple collection-manipulating method calls into a one-liner. This can make the code more fluent and readable.

Answer (score -1):

Both methods work, although in Java, I think that the first one is the most used.